# ElasticSearch High Level Rest Client search single field with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the ElasticSearch high level rest Java client and want to know if it is possible to use the single search API to search for documents matching a single field with multiple values.

For example, I want to search by an id and want to provide multiple ids. Like this:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("userId", "123")); 
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("userId", "321"));
```

What I think is happening is the latest one overrides the previous so I always get the result matching 321 back. Is there a way to do this in a single search or do you have to use the Multi-Search API for these kinds of searches?

Comment: Although the given answer works, it’s s bit cumbersome. You’re looking for the terms-query which is meant for exactly this usecase: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: I don't see a way to use the terms query to match on multiple terms in multiple fields together without using the bool query. If you know how, please provide an example.

Comment: That’s a different question though. You asked to search for multiple values in the same field. If you want to search for different values in a different field as well, than yes, wrapping multiple a terms-query with whatever other query you need in a bool-query works jus fine. Note the difference between terms-query and term-query here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using bool query. I created an outer MUST with inner SHOULD queries. Here is an example.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "term": {
              "customerId": "123123123"
            }
          }, {
            "term": {
              "customerId": "5345345345"
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "match": {
              "location": "japan"
            }
          }]          
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could u post java version for this, or do u anyone know some online utility which can convert dsl query to java code